# $('#name').val() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand. I even tried to copy my other webpage's code for the getting of an input's value, and it perfectly works on that page, while here, it still doesn't work. the code for the input field is this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" id="name" size="10" style="bottom:570px;left:964px;position: relative">
```

while for the button,

```
<button type="button" style="bottom:600px;left:1100px;position: relative" id="addbutt" onclick="addu()">Add Button</button>
```

I am not sure though if it has something to do with the order, because the button was written before the input field. But I tried to rearrange it, and I still get the same result.

the javascript code is:

```
alert("helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo tang---");
var nem = $('#name').val();
alert(nem);
```

when I press the button, only the alert `helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo tang---` shows up, but the other alert does not. I even tried to remove the first alert, and it still does not show. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do you have the $ variable defined? As in do you have jQuery referenced properly?

Comment: Any errors on dev tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working. Check whether you have included jQuery or not.
Working codepen [is here](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/ZaRBpM)

```
function addu(){
  alert("helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo tang---");
  //var nem = $('#name').val();
  var nem=document.getElementById('name').value
  alert(nem);
}
```

this code doesn't require you to include jQuery. If you want your code to run than include jQuery.

JavaScript is faster than using jQuery. See this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22)
and run test yourself and compare.

Javascript `var $el = document.getElementById('hello')` can run 27,091,679 ops/sec while jQuery one `var $el = $('#hello');` will run only 1,430,757 ops/sec

So using jQuery is 95% slower than using JavaScript.

Comment: I used to get the value that way, but I prefer the shortest code possible that's why I use jQuery, thank you.

Comment: @hpa if I say shorter come at cost of performance than what will you choose shorter or performance one?

Comment: @shiladitya is it more faster compared to jQuery? well if that's so, of course I wouldn't mind working with longer codes

Comment: @hpa I have update answer with link to performance compare link. jQuery is 95% slower than JavaScript in simple selection

Comment: @hpa why you are tagging me?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code or your lib:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: thank you so much! Darn, how stupid of me to forget that.